# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function call_user_method()

Tags: php, php7

soy nuevo en php y tengo este problema con mi codigo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function call_user_method()...

es sin dudas un problema con php dado que ee aparentemente por una función que ya no se usa desde 4.1, pero usando php 5.3 y me dice:

> Deprecated: Function call_user_method() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\rlra-php-master\app\core\Lb.php on line 45

pego el código que me marca el problema acá:

```
<?php
class Lb {
    public function Lb(){
        $this->get = new Get();
        $this->post = new Post();
        $this->request = new Request();
        $this->cookie = new Cookie();
        $this->session = new Session();
        $this->default_controller ="index";
        $this->default_view ="index";
    }
    public function loadModule($module){
            if(!isset($_GET['module'])){
                if(isset($_GET["r"])){
                    $d = explode("/", $_GET["r"]);
                    if(count($d)!=2){
                        echo "Invalid R parameters";
                        exit;
                    }else{
                        if($d[0]!=""&&$d[1]!=""){
                            $this->default_controller = $d[0];
                            $this->default_view = $d[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                $this->default_controller = $this->default_controller."Controller";
                require_once "app/controllers/".$this->default_controller.".php";
                $controller = new $this->default_controller;
                $method = $this->default_view."Action";
                if(method_exists($controller, $method)){
                    $data = call_user_method($method, $controller);
                }else{
                    echo "<b>".$method."</b> not found in ".$this->default_controller;
                }
            }else{
            }
    }
}a
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví cambiando:

```
$data = call_user_method(method, $controller);
```

por:

```
$data = call_user_func(array($controller, $method ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues de acuerdo con la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/call_user_method):

> Advertencia
>   Esta función está OBSOLETA en PHP 4.1.0, por lo tanto, será ELIMINADA en PHP 7.0.0.

Dado lo anterior entonces no importa si usas PHP 5.X o PHP 7.X en ambos casos lo marcará como *deprecated* o desaconsejada de uso.

Mientras que se te ofrece una función alterna llamada: **`call_user_func()`**, la cual puedes aplicar de esta forma:

```
function hola($name)
{
    return "Hola {$name}";
}

echo call_user_func('hola', $name = "you");
```

Detalles de uso:

- Al pasar como argumento el nombre de la función, este debe ir entre comillas como un *string*
- Adicional como argumento también separado por una coma debe ir el valor que espera la función que están invocando en el punto anterior mencionado

**REFERENCIAS**

- [**`call_user_func(......)`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: Hola, si lo lei pero como he intentado modificar el codigo con dicha funcion y no he podido por eso consulte, porque nupe modificarlo con esa funcion...imaginé que era esta parte del codigo; $method = $this->default_view."Action"; y de ahi para adelante, pero lo intente sin resultado..